# How to compare a given date from today

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to compare a given date to today and here is the condition: If provided date is greater than or equal to 6 months earlier from today, return true else return false

Code:

```
string strDate = tbDate.Text; //2015-03-29
if (DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6) == DateTime.Parse(strDate)) //if given date is equal to exactly 6 months past from today (change == to > if date has to be less 6 months)
{
    lblResult.Text = "true"; //this doesn't work with the entered date above.
}
else //otherwise give me the date which will be 6 months from a given date.
{
    DateTime dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(strDate);
    lblResult.Text = "6 Months from given date is: " + dt2.AddMonths(6); //this works fine
}
```

- If 6 months or greater than 6 months is what I would like for one
  condition
- If less than 6 months is another condition.

Comment: How exact? Does the time of day count?

Comment: if time doesnt count change now with Today

Comment: @WaiHaLee Just months. Thank you.

Comment: What about February 30?

Comment: the function addmonths will not make january 30th to february 30 -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths(v=vs.110).aspx whats wrong with your current code? change now with today and from the current date strDate keep only the date or set the time to 00:00:00 (just like .Today does)

Comment: @CDrosos sure... but it is somewhat too vague: "a month from now" is fine in spoken text, but could mean different things in code - if it is ok to change day sometime (Jan 31->Feb 28) why should not it be acceptable to make that change all the time (Mar 31 -> Apr 28)? (Anyway OP clearly needs just month and my comment was not useful).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your first problem is that you're using `DateTime.Now` instead of `DateTime.Today` - so subtracting 6 months will give you another `DateTime` with a particular time of day, which is very unlikely to be *exactly* the date/time you've parsed. For the rest of this post, I'm assuming that the value you parse is really a date, so you end up with a `DateTime` with a time-of-day of midnight. (Of course, in my very biased view, it would be better to use [a library which supports "date" as a first class concept](http://nodatime.org)...)

The next problem is that you are assuming that subtracting 6 months from today and comparing it with a fixed date is equivalent to adding 6 months to the fixed date and comparing it with today. They're not the same operation - calendar arithmetic just doesn't work like that. You should work out which way you want it to work, and be consistent. For example:

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Parse(tbDate.Text);
DateTime end = start.AddMonths(6);
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
if (end >= today)
{
    // Today is 6 months or more from the start date
}
else
{
    // ...
}
```

Or alternatively - and *not* equivalently:

```
DateTime target = DateTime.Parse(tbDate.Text);
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime sixMonthsAgo = today.AddMonths(-6);
if (sixMonthsAgo >= target)
{
    // Six months ago today was the target date or later
}
else
{
    // ...
}
```

Note that you should only evaluate `DateTime.Today` (or `DateTime.Now` etc) *once* per set of calculations - otherwise you could find it changes between evaluations.

Comment: Sorry, here is the condition: If provided date is greater than or equal to 6 months from today, return true else return false.

Comment: @SiKni8: 6 months *later* than today, or 6 months *earlier* than today? And do you understand that's different to "6 months from the given date is today or later"?

Comment: 6 months earlier from today. sorry

Comment: @SiKni8: Right, well I've edited my answer to explain this, but you really should edit your question to be a *lot* clearer - with examples. Please bear in mind the differences between "today - 6 months" and "target date + 6 months".

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
DateTime s = Convert.ToDateTime(tbDate.Text);
s = s.Date;

if (DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-6) == s) //if given date is equal to exactly 6 months past from today (change == to > if date has to be less 6 months)
{
lblResult.Text = "true"; //this doesn't work with the entered date above.
}
```

replace == with >= or <= according to your needs

Comment: What's the point of `s = s.Date + ts`?  `s = s.Date` would give the same result.

Comment: no it only take the date from s and gives the time 00:00:00

Comment: `ts` is 0. So adding it will not change anything.

Comment: i think you are right, so we only need to keep the date